# Windows Phone 7 and 8 with PhoneGap + Angular dies during bootstrapping

Tags: javascript, angularjs, windows-phone-8, cordova

- Windows Phone 7 or 8
- PhoneGap 3
- AngularJS 1.2

I have a PhoneGap app using AngularJS that works great on iOS and Android, but I'm having a problem getting it to work on Windows Phone 7 and 8.

The app starts fine and I see my index.html page (which in my case is just a loading screen). Source files are loaded and my pre-boot code is running fine.

Then it stops and nothing happens.

I've littered "console.log" messages throughout the code and I see it gets to the point of `angular.bootstrap()` and then dies. I'm not familiar enough with angular to know what to do next or how to debug this further to track down what the absolute problem code might be. Inside of bootstrap() begins the maze of DI calls so the code becomes much less linear.

I do see this error in the console but have no idea what it means or how to fix it:

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
```

No other errors or any output is logged to the console. I tried delaying all of my bootstrap code by 10 seconds with a setTimeout and that error is always reported before `angular.bootstrap()` is called, so I don't know if it is even related.

Also worth noting that I've tried the app in IE on the desktop and it works fine there.

So my question is: How do I go about debugging this?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace when you try to run it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem? I have a very similar problem, although I never see any errors in the console. I did locate an issue with this line in Angular: `var injector = createInjector(modules);` which appears to fail if I have dependencies in my app module, but seems to run without them. I still get a blank screen either way.

Comment: I think I may have a found a solution to this problem.  I was able to get a simple example up and running, I posted some code snippets on this github thread here:   https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4288  , if people are interested I can put a sample app on my github so everyone can see the source code but you should be able to get it working with the snippets I posted, it worked for me with angular 1.2, windows phone 8, and phonegap 3.2 RC1

Answer (score 2):

I am unsure of WP7/8 but if it follows Windows 8 pattern try adding JQuery 2.0 before angular.js

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-windows-store-applications-with-jquery-2-0/

Comment: There is also a patched version of 1.8 available but I had success using 2.0 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jason, use Windows special/custom jQuery. And add `unsafe=true`

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2-win8-1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.isUnsafe = true;
</script>
```

The functionality of the Windows 8-patch had been included in jQuery 2.0. So can just use jQuery 2.0 in the same way, and it will work'.

So you can also use:

```
<script src="/lib/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery.isUnsafe = true;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this error is relevant because it is present even if you start Cordova/Phongap template app (I tried with Cordova  2.9.0). Visual Studio dosen't give any good explanation why app is not running, that's why I tried weinre and got the following massage on app reloade with angular-1.0.8

```
Error: Access is denied.
at hookedFunction (http://"my-weinre-ip":8080/target/target-script-min.js#ddtest:551:1)
at Anonymous function (x-wmapp0://www/components/angular/angular.js:9457:7)
at sendReq (x-wmapp0://www/components/angular/angular.js:9334:9)
at $http (x-wmapp0://www/components/angular/angular.js:9125:7)
at Anonymous function (x-wmapp0://www/components/angular/angular.js:9268:11)
at Anonymous function (x-wmapp0://www/components/angular/angular.js:7592:17)
at wrappedCallback (x-wmapp0://www/components/angular/angular.js:6996:15)
at wrappedCallback (x-wmapp0://www/components/angular/angular.js:6996:15)
at Anonymous function (x-wmapp0://www/components/angular/angular.js:7033:11)
at $eval (x-wmapp0://www/components/angular/angular.js:8219:9)
```

I reported it to angular [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4288)

**EDIT**

I managed to get a basic angular app running in phonegap WP7 (haven't tested it yet on WP8)  by

1. applying fix  from github ( I can't post second link not enough reputation)

   @github/RobbinHabermehl/angular.js/commit/2645faad908529b5d33af960270755dd65a9aa78
2. including jquery (2.0.3) above angular.js
3. changing line of code in angular from

   var xhr = new XHR();

to

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

1. manually bootstrapping angular app after cordova deviceready event fired

I reported it in my original thread [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4288)

Comment: I replied on your original thread in github, I was able to get routing working after numerous attempts and it has to do with whitelisting url's in the config as angular for some reason does not trust them in WP8 applications.  If it resolves your issue let me know and i will post it here as well as a solution, it worked for me but not sure it will work for everyone